# Why does typescript infer unknown with a recursive type?

Tags: typescript

Why is `U` being inferred as `unknown` in `foo`?

Could it not look at `UnwrappedArray` and known that `U` must be a `string` or yet another `UnwrappedArray`?

Is there any hints that I can give to the compiler to help it out?

```
type Unwrap<T> = T extends string ? T : T extends Array<infer U> ? UnwrappedArray<U> : never;
interface UnwrappedArray<T> extends Array<Unwrap<T>> {}

let a: string = "hello";
let b: Unwrap<string> = a;
a = b;

let c: Array<string> = [a];
let d: Unwrap<Array<string>> = c;
c = d;

function foo<A>(unwrapped: Unwrap<A>): A {
    // This fails.
    return unwrapped;
}
```

```
Type 'Unwrap<A>' is not assignable to type 'A'.
  'A' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Unwrap<A>'.
    Type 'A | (A extends (infer U)[] ? UnwrappedArray<U> : never)' is not assignable to type 'A'.
      'A' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'A | (A extends (infer U)[] ? UnwrappedArray<U> : never)'.
        Type 'A extends (infer U)[] ? UnwrappedArray<U> : never' is not assignable to type 'A'.
          'A' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'A extends (infer U)[] ? UnwrappedArray<U> : never'.
            Type 'UnwrappedArray<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'A'.
              'A' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'UnwrappedArray<unknown>'.(2322)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgdwE4EMwB4AqA+KBeKTKCAD2AjgBMBnKa4JASzgHMoB+QqALi9PKq0AgklQh0zAGYQksXJ3jI0kSiLHoYuXnAgA3GQG4AUM3JJJKAMbRFqMCrUpxOYmQo0oj8bbRZsuAG8AXyMjABsIYCgUXnomVnwoACIACwgwsIB7JOMIqIAjXh8MOOYWXAIUYxRE-ONwyKhLXi90UtYKqABtFABdXMbKIsQ7dFb28s7LY0tEynrJAFc4S2BGTLgoSUzMsewACmWlewgh2BHfIWwAShaoAKMoJ6gkSMWkTaO7FWMgoA)

Comment: What should `Unwrap<T>` do? I didn't get it.

Comment: It extracts the type out of the array. See https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/nodejs/pulumi/pulumi/#output for a more realistic use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give a counter example, let's just think when `A` is `['1']` type, so when we use `type Unwrap<A>` to  transform it, due to `interface UnwrappedArray<T> extends Array<Unwrap<T>> {}`, finally, `UnwrappedArray<U>` would be equal to `Array<'1'>` which is not initial type `['1']`. This is demonstrated by:

```
let e: Array<"hello"> = ["hello"];
let f: Unwrap<Array<string>> = e;
// Counter example.
e = f;
```

To solve this problem, you can try the following change:

```
type Unwrap<T> = T extends string
  ? T
  : T extends Array<infer U>
    // U extends Unwrap<U>, the following line can be simplified like that, thx for the suggestion 
    ? U extends Unwrap<U>
      ? T
      : never
    : never;

let a: string = "hello";
let b: Unwrap<string> = a;
a = b;

let c: Array<string> = [a];
let d: Unwrap<Array<string>> = c;
c = d;

function foo<A>(unwrapped: Unwrap<A>): A {
    return unwrapped;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgdwE4EMwB4AqA%20KBeKTKCAD2AjgBMBnKa4JASzgHMAoKKAfkI6gC5CxMhRpQAgklQh0zAGYQksbH0494yNJEqTp6GCs6dBcCADdFAbjbNySOSgDG0DajDbdKGTmHkqtTxlXNCxsXABvAF82NgAbCGAoFEF6JlZ8KAAiAAsIWNiAe0zreMSAI0FgjFTmFlwCFGsUDLLrOISoR0FA9BrWeqgAbRQAXRKOykrEN3QevrqBx2tHDMo2uQBXOEdgRgK4KDkCgtnsAAotzXcISdhpkPFsAEpuqHC%20AHoPwmzGWgdGLFqAA6PhIBIbJAHS5ubTWaLtRIQbpSLzoHJ5QqZAaDDH5IpjRGHKZXWaomTzMIZCDWL5QADCBS2dmEKAAtmB4qDoAQ5G06ZhfrQ-lBgLlDowSKDQJA7lcAEyhDJEUh%20MTzPg8TB8QQqkT%20CTk2RwBRKAyqbiwXyiWhVfSGIxqXiO4xQUwWJAWkzmKwxTbbXb7Q7HRWPC73a63Kqh56vd6ccHASHQiNwtjRIA)

Comment: What is type `['1']`? Are you saying there are two different array types? The constraint on `U` does work though and can be simplified to `U extends Unwrap<U>`.

Comment: Yeah, type `['1']` means that type of Array that only include one element `1`, but when it's used via `interface X extends`, that is equal to `['1'] & '1'[ ]`  =  `'1'[ ]`, which is not the initial type `['1']`

Comment: Ah right yes. I hope you don't mind me making this more explicit in your answer.